# File/socket descriptor table

Tags: linux-kernel, file-descriptor

I'm curious to know how the per-process file/socket descriptor table is implemented in Linux. Specifically, which data structure(s) and algorithms are used to implement it and keep it efficient.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Opened files by a process are managed by struct files_struct, which is in the process's struct task_struct

```
struct task_struct {
    ...
    /* open file information */
    struct files_struct *files;
```

The per-process file descriptor table (fdt) is in struct files_struct

```
struct files_struct {
    ...
    struct fdtable __rcu *fdt;
```

When a process is trying to open a file, it issues a open syscall. Which will call sys_open. This is basically the code flow:

```
sys_open(filename, …)
    // 1)   copy filename from user space
    getname(filename)
            strncpy_from_user()
    // 2)  get first unused file descriptor (will be returned to process)
    int fd = get_unused_fd()
        struct files_struct *files = current->files
    // 3) get file from filesystem
    struct file *f = file_open(filename)
        open_namei
            // lookup operation for filesystem
            dentry = cached_lookup or real_lookup 
            // initializes file struct
            dentry_open 
    // 4) install file returned by filesystem into file descriptor table for the process
    fd_install
        current->files->fd[fd] = file
```

The process gets in return the index to the file descriptor table for the file opened.